# Boost Asio. Очередь обработчиков

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, asio

Есть, например, этот код:

```
int main() {

boost::asio::io_service service;
auto work = boost::asio::make_work_guard(service);

boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{ service };
boost::asio::io_service::strand strand{ service };

std::string address{ "192.168.1.13" };
std::string port{ "8002" };
boost::asio::streambuf input{512};

boost::asio::thread_pool pool(1);
boost::asio::post(pool, [&service]()
    {
        try {
            service.run();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ::std::cout << "Catch" << ::std::endl;
        }
    }
);

auto lambda = [&input](auto er, auto tr) {
    if (!er) {
        ::std::cout << tr << ::std::endl;
        ::std::istream st{ &input };
        ::std::string target;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tr; ++i)
            target += st.get();
    }
    else {
        ::std::cout << er.message() << ::std::endl;
    }
};

socket.async_connect(
    {
        boost::asio::ip::make_address(address),
        boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(port)
    },
    boost::asio::bind_executor(
        strand,
        [](auto& er) {
            if (!er)
                ::std::cout << "Success" << ::std::endl;
            else {
                ::std::cout << "Error" << ::std::endl;
            }
        }
    )
);

boost::asio::async_read_until(
    socket,
    input,
    "/r/n",
    boost::asio::bind_executor(
        strand, 
        lambda
   )
);

boost::asio::async_read_until(
    socket,
    input,
    "/r/n",
    boost::asio::bind_executor(
        strand,
        lambda
    )
);

work.reset();
pool.join();
service.stop();

return 0;
}
```

И вывод из asio:

```
@asio|1550142117.477501|0*1|thread_pool@00E2FB60.post
@asio|1550142117.477501|>1|
@asio|1550142117.535496|0*2|socket@00E2FC24.async_connect
@asio|1550142117.536498|0*3|socket@00E2FC24.async_receive
@asio|1550142117.536498|0*4|socket@00E2FC24.async_receive
@asio|1550142117.536498|>3|ec=system:10057,bytes_transferred=0
@asio|1550142117.536498|3*5|strand@00E46A68.dispatch
@asio|1550142117.536498|>5|
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
@asio|1550142117.537497|<5|
@asio|1550142117.537497|<3|
@asio|1550142117.537497|>4|ec=system:10057,bytes_transferred=0
@asio|1550142117.537497|4*6|strand@00E46A68.dispatch
@asio|1550142117.537497|>6|
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
@asio|1550142117.537497|<6|
@asio|1550142117.537497|<4|
@asio|1550142117.537497|>2|ec=system:0
@asio|1550142117.537497|2*7|strand@00E46A68.dispatch
@asio|1550142117.537497|>7|
Success
@asio|1550142117.537497|<7|
@asio|1550142117.537497|<2|
@asio|1550142127.536385|<1|
```

**Вопрос:** На каком основании `async_read_until` выполняется раньше `async_connect` и как мне это избежать? `boost::asio::io_service::strand` отказывается помогать.

**Дополнение:** Я нашел причину в документации [Strand](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html) -

> Note that in the following case:
>   `async_op_1(..., s.wrap(a)); async_op_2(..., s.wrap(b));` the completion of the first async operation will perform s.dispatch(a), and the second will perform s.dispatch(b), but the order in which those are performed is unspecified. That is, you cannot state whether one happens-before the other. Therefore none of the above conditions are met and no ordering guarantee is made.

Но от это не легче.

**Оставшийся вопрос:** Как мне это избежать, не меняя вышестояющую последовательность, т.е. последовательно вызывать async_* команды и выполнять их только в той последовательности?

**UDP:** Путем углубленного анализа документации, что надо было делать с самого начала, я понял, что async_* функции имеют несколько этапов и их не следует вызывать в одном потоке. Но это не сказано для async_connect в сокете. Проблема опережения чтения также осталась неизвестной.

Comment: Что-то не очень понятно, какого результата вы ожидаете создавая запрос на чтение когда сокет еще не был открыт?

Comment: @VTT, Моя мысль была такая: поток один, значит заботиться о синхронизации смысла нет. Можно сделать что-то на подобие сценария (Допустим, сказали открыть сокет, прочитать 3 раза, написать один раз, закрыть сокет) работы. Но не вышло. Это всё-таки не является очередью в полноценном смысле. Ожидал я последовательного выполнения открытия соединения и двух операций чтения.

Comment: Потоков у вас два... И нет, эти операции не будут последовательными даже если бы это все выполнялось в одном потоке. Чтобы они были последовательными следующую операцию придется начинать в обработчике предыдущей или сходным способом.

Comment: @VTT, Я имел в виду поток в котором выполняется обработка коллбеков `io_service`, а не текущий.

Comment: @VTT, в любом случае меня интересует причина, по которой `async_connect` выполняется последним.

Comment: А тут вовсе не факт что он выполняется последним. Вполне возможна ситуация, когда соединение происходит до запросов на чтение, или между ними, или вообще не происходит. Заметьте, что `async_connect` выполняется как раз строго первым, но это только инициализация операции, а вот функция обратного вызова срабатывает при завершении операции - когда-нибудь потом.

Comment: @VTT, именно в этом примере внутренний dispatch на соединение выполняется последним. Я пробовал разную последовательность, но `async_connect` был всегда последним. Скорее всего так звёзды сошлись.

Comment: Попробуйте вставить sleep на секунду после async_connect

Comment: @VTT, так-то сработает) Это не интересно.